# jQuery remove specific td from specific table

Tags: jquery

Cant seem to get this to work without removing all tr's and tables but one. I am trying to remove all countries except for 2 td's from this specific form table but I cant get the syntax correct for nothing.

```
$("table .country_id td .value").attr("name='location[country_id]'").not("select > option[value='GR']" ||  "select > option[value='CY']").remove();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Note: code below:

```
<div class="location_container">
<table class="form">
<tbody>
<tr class="country_id">
<td class="label">Country<span class="required_star">*</span></td>
<td class="value">
<select name="location[country_id]">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="AX">Aland Islands</option>
... and so on
```

Comment: [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) loads html attributes for the element selected. It doesn't select things. Use `[name='location[country_id']` to select elements with a certain attribute (like the answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the basic idea down, just think your not selector wasn't formatted properly.

```
$('.country_id').find('option').not('[value="GR"], [value="CY"]').remove();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ferne97/QcmRn/2/)

Comment: this is perfect. Thank you! I knew I was close, just something was not right. woohoo

Answer (score 1):

Try using [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$(".country_id td.value [name^=location] option").filter(function(){
   return !(this.value=='GR' || this.value == CY);
}).remove();
```

Comment: You need `==` instead of the first `=` and `'CY'` instead of just `CY`, but this works.

Comment: this is removing only values GR and CY. I want to remove everything Except these two values. sorry for any confusion..

Comment: this is good. I see your logic, I like it, I wish I could say answered to two answers, but the other guys code is cleaner and more towards what I was going for. Is there a reason to use filter and not .find and .not?